# Recursive critical sections in Go

Tags: recursion, concurrency, go, mutex

I understand that there is no support for recursive mutexes in Go (and that a lot of folks consider these dangerous), and that channels are the preferred way to implement complex concurrency patterns.

However, I cannot figure out any sensible way to implement a very common concurrency pattern - that of the re-entrant or recursive critical section.

Roughly:   goroutines A and B will compete for a lock over a critical section (say some state in a struct needs to be atomically modified).  Let's say A receives the lock.  However, A will recurse, possibly needing to enter the critical section many times.  When it has exited the critical section as it has entered it, goroutine B will get the lock, etc.

I want to implement this with channels (or in any way possible in Go otherwise), without having to pass some string or token back and forth through the whole call tree of functions that might pass through the critical section (there is no "goroutine id" available)., and without having messy/expensive stack introspection necessary using `runtime` package.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Say, your example above looks like:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    // here must be reentrant mutex
    Value int
}

var F Foo

func A() {
    F.Value += 1
    if F.Value < 10 {
        A()
    }
}

func B() {
    F.Value += 5
    if F.Value < 20 {
        A()
    }
}

func main() {
    F = Foo{
        Value: 0,
    }
    A()
    B()
    fmt.Println("F is", F.Value)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/STnaLUCaqP

Then implementation in channels should follow simple principle - only one place where F.Value is read or written, wrapped by *select* statement. Something like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    Value int
}

var (
    F  Foo
    ch = make(chan int)
)

func A() {
    val := <-ch
    ch <- val+1
    if val < 10 {
        A()
    }
}

func B() {
    val := <-ch
    ch <- val+5
    if val < 20 {
        A()
    }
}

func main() {
    F = Foo{
        Value: 0,
    }
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case val := <-ch:
                F.Value = val
            case ch <- F.Value:
            }
        }
    }()
    A()
    B()
    fmt.Println("F is", F.Value)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/e5M4vTeet2

Here we use bidirectional buffered channel for getting/setting F.Value. One reader, one writer, select does all the magic to handling access.

You may also be interested in relevant topic in golang-nuts on the reentrant mutexes: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/vN5ncBdtkcA There are good explanation why reentrant mutexes are not useful in Go (and it's not the question of danger).

Comment: Your A() and B() are explicitly synchronous/serialized; you are not implementing the concurrency pattern I am talking about.  In your example B starts after A finishes.  Now - start both A and B invocations as goroutines, and (assuming A gets the channel first) ensure that B's invocation of A blocks until the first invocation frame of A completes, and we're closer to what I want.  The problem is that there is no way I can see for a select or any other concurrency mechanism in the language to distinguish between B's first invocation of A, and A's first, second, third, etc...

Comment: As for that link,  "Code that takes the lock, and then takes it again appears to be written in a very sloppy way (in my opinion)."

Some people I know say any/all recursion is "sloppy".   They're entitled to their opinions, I guess.

Comment: Looks like the best bet here is going to be going with some kind of worker queue pattern, where A and B are passed along with their arguments over a channel and called reflectively, in a single goroutine, in serial order.  Initial testing looks like this is a huge performance hit, but I can't see any other way...   hopefully some Go guru will have something further to say on this.... =/

Comment: Yes, in this specific example A() and B() start synchronously, but I made that intentionaly to simplify the code. You can add 'go' keyword to A() and B() and implement WaitGroup or even add time.Sleep() to wait until A() and B() finished. But this code shows the core idea.

Regarding performance, you usually don't have huge performance hit, there are a lot of benchmarks about that, see https://github.com/mdmarek/go-lock-vs-channel for example.

Also there is nice and precise wiki page on where to use mutexes and channels in Go: https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/MutexOrChannel.

Comment: I think you're not understanding what I'm asking for...   You can't just add 'go' in front of A and B.  If you do, it's possible that at some point in the resulting execution the channel will send the value 12 - say one goroutine has a stack of A 6 frames deep and another has a B > A, 2 frames deep.  That would not be allowed if the code was properly guarding according to my constraints. (again assuming the A() call executes first - the other way you should not see a value like 7).

Comment: If you can provide an example using WaitGroup that prevents an A under a B from executing concurrently with another goroutine invocation of A, I'd love to see it - WaitGroup had the most promise but I think you'd still need a goroutine identifier.

Comment: Yeah, I guess, I misunderstood your constraints. But your constraints are inherently described using locks terminology, so probably it's better to ask for the real-world example of the situation to understand how to re-implement them.